# nodejs run eval inside of testcase

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, eval, chai

I need to run some eval code inside of a mocha test in nodejs, but I keep running into an issue. I cannot do any var declarations inside of a test. So, if I have something like this:

```
it("7.Variable Assignment", function(done){
    eval("var testVar = 1;");
    expect(testVar).eql(1);
    done();

});
```

The test returns:

```
   7.Variable Assignment:
 ReferenceError: testVar is not defined
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (test/index.js:102:16), <anonymous>:1:1)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.js:102:16)
```

But if I change it to:

```
it("7.Variable Assignment", function(done){
        var testVar;
        eval("testVar = 1;");
        expect(testVar).eql(1);
        done();

    });
```

The test passes. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?
EDIT: I need to do variable declarations inside the string.

Comment: What is the purpose of this test ?  
Why can't you do a variable declaration inside of a test ?

Comment: This is an obviously simplified version of my real tests. I'm testing a babel plugin.

Comment: Hm, it's not evident to answer with so few elements. Is it possible to put directly the ouput into `expect`, like `expect(eval("testVar = 1;")).eq(1);` ?
Can't you declare the variable `testVar` outside of the test ?
In any case use `eval` function is not recommanded [for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/9640261)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I need to do variable declarations in a string.

Comment: This is the kind of useful information for helping answering to your problem..
If you must use eval (is it the case ?): `expect(eval("var testVar; testVar = 1; testVar")).eq(1);`

Comment: Yeah, that seems to do the trick, thanks. I will keep this question open incase someone gives me a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do any variable declaration and you must use eval, you can directly test eval's output:

```
expect(eval("var testVar; testVar = 1; testVar")).eq(1);
```